# Java.Lang.LinkageError: no non-static method on Xamarin.Android peculiar to Nougat only

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I've been running the below code successfully on KitKat and Marshmallow, until I tested it on Nougat and it began to crash.

Here is a snippet from my code.

`public GoogleApiClient GApiClient { get; private set; }`

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if(GApiClient == null)
        {
            GApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .AddApi(DriveClass.API)
            .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeFile)
            .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeAppfolder)
            .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .Build();
        }
        GApiClient.Connect();
    }
```

After I successful get a connection I execute this somewhere within the code.

```
if (GApiClient != null && GApiClient.IsConnected)
{
     await LoadCloudItems();
}

private async Task LoadCloudItems()
{
    IDriveFolder appFolder = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(GApiClient);
    // app already crashes at this point, without getting to the next line.
    //... some other async code
}
```

Which results in this error:

```
Java.Lang.LinkageError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbio;.getAppFolder(Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;)Lcom/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder;"
```

I've tested this code severally on Android 4.4 and 6.0, without any problem.
I've perfomed clean, rebuild all etc on my VS2017 project, all to no avail.

This issue has persisted throughout several updated to my app, and I don't know why it keeps failing on Nougat only.

Comment: If it works on older versions, maybe you need to update to the latest versions?

Comment: Hi noogui. Latest version of what? The app will not crash if installed on a device with Android 6.0 or below. I cannot force app users to update their android version.

Comment: Did you install some nuget package? You could check their dependencies and make sure the package you installed is working on Nougat.